# QGIS - is it possible to select the columns shown with "Identify features"?

Tags: attribute-table, qgis-2

In QGIS, I have created a join to an attribute table with some 60 entries. I am only interested in seeing 3 of the columns, specifically address data.
I can see no way of excluding the unwanted columns from the “identify features” tool.
Can anyone help?

Comment: If I have understood you correct you want only 3 columns be visible.
To do It you have to go in to properties of layer - Fields - and choose for fields you don't wont to be visible - hidden (in field edit widget).
After that open your attribute table and you will not see fields you' have made hidden.

Comment: Same effect also to the "Identify features" tool. You could well convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this, Guys, problem solved. This is the first time I've used this facility and cant believe the quick response

Comment: @bable I can't see what you're explaining here - could you give a bit more detail and put the response in the 'answer' section below? Thanks!